# His genitive - will this be understood by contemporary people?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to make a game as a hobby project... And I've run into an issue of how to implement genitive in such a way that I don't violate English grammar rules.

One problem I don't see a clear solution with is what the narrator should say when two players are fighting via their creatures. When the person to whom the narrator's message is addressed is also a player, this seems fairly easy:

> Your creaturename has stolen XX life from enemy's creaturename!

But what when the narrator's message is addressed to a spectator? Then words such as "*your*" or *enemy's* are senseless.

One obvious solution is to do this:

> Player1Nick's creaturename has stolen XX life from Player2Nick's creaturename!

But I don't want to go down that way because of [problems](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/when-a-word-ends-in-s-or-x-do-you-add-s-or-just-an/6320#6320). If I do, I'll inevitably introduce grammar errors depending on a player's nick.

> creaturename of Player1Nick has stolen XX life from creaturename of Player2Nick!

This seems promising, but... looks ugly to me in some circumstances:

> The attack has aggravated the poisoning of creaturename of Player2Nick!

Still, maybe this is the correct way to go.

But I have one more crazy idea... Why not use the [his genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_genitive)?

I'm thinking of stuff like this:

> Player1Nick their creaturename has stolen XX life from Player2Nick their creaturename!
>
> The attack has aggravated the poisoning of Player2Nick their creaturename!

Hence my question, will this be understood? I know this seems overly fancy and will cause some surprise... but will this be even understood? Or will a contemporary just stare at a notice like that, unable to comprehend it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to translate RPG status messages from "computer listing" format to natural English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But this is still about English, isn't it?

Comment: Why not simply say *Player1Nick has stolen life from Player2Nick*? Isn't it assumed that they are fighting each other through avatars? I doubt that anybody would take it literally.

Comment: @JasonBassford Would be nice, but... Their creatures are their primary (actually only) means to fight. The game is... A little bit inspired by Pokemon. The creatures are what is important, the player nicks are just to make it very clear to which team does a creature belong to... and to disambiguate the case when both players have sent the same species of creatures to fight each other.

Comment: In that case, why not give names to the creatures and just refer to them by name? Perhaps something like "*Creature1Name (Player1Nick) has stolen life from Creature2Name (Player2Nick) . . .*"

Comment: I think all the above, Question and Comments, looks at style or choice or proof-reading or programming, none of which belongs here. I suggest the problem is trying to translate your project into English so early. Why would it be a problem to work in your own language, and afterwards translate what really needs to be translated? Either way why not assume everyone interested will remember Creaturename goes with Playername, and use something like "Creaturename has stolen XX from Creaturename"?

Comment: What is wrong with "Player1Nick's creaturename"? That you don't know whether Player1Nick is singular, plural, or even possessive? Is saying "The Bees' Knees's dragon" that much of a disaster? It's much better that "The Bees Knees their dragon".

Comment: @PeterShor Quite right, "The Bees' Knees's dragon" is little worse that "The Court of St James's" which has a long and distinguished history. The alternative is to prevent the creation of nicknames with aportrophes in them, that would solve most of the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a number of answers given in the comments; I will try to condense them into an actual answer.

First, you should *not* use

> 1. Amy their dragon has stolen life from Leslie their sea serpent.

The construction *Lord Voldemort his horcruces* was mainly used with *his* (rarely with *her*), by a relatively small set of authors, and several centuries ago. It sounds very wrong to today's ears.

There are several suggestions from the comments:

You could use your suggestion:

> 2. The dragon of Amy has stolen life from the sea serpent of Leslie.

This sounds awkward.

You could also use

> 3. The dragon (Amy) has stolen life from the sea serpent (Leslie).

Again, this sounds awkward.

You could have everybody give all of their creatures a name:

> 4. Smaug has stolen life from Nessie.

The problem with this is that everybody has to remember all the players' creatures' names.

You could go ahead and use the *'s* possessive:

> 5. Amy's dragon has stolen life from Leslie's sea serpent.

This sounds fine for the vast majority of names. There are some playernames that it sounds bad for — for example multi-syllable names ending in /-iz/ or /əz/ like *Euripides* or *Moses*, and plural names like *The Wasps*. But it doesn't sound horrible; both of these are still better than (1) and maybe only slightly worse than (2) and (3).

> Euripides's dragon has stolen life from The Wasps's sea serpent.

My suggestions would be either (3) or (5), but it's possible that some native English speakers would prefer (2). Don't use (1).